# Regex with StreamReader

Tags: c#, regex, streamreader

I have interesting problem with streamreader.

my code:

```
    string file, text;
    MatchCollection mcol;
    private void btnGozat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        file = "c:/filelist.txt";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@file,Encoding.Default);
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Regex myreg = new Regex(@"[\d]{1,10}\n{1}(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s*([\w ığüşöçĞÜŞİÖÇâêî.!" + "\"" + @":'\-\\?\^,\s]*)(\n)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        mcol = myreg.Matches(text);//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< care this row

        for (int i = 0; i < mcol.Count; i++)
        {
            cbList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I trying this code mcol.Count be 0 and any items not adding `cbList.`
but when I text variable writing richtextbox1 and I change this row row to "`mcol = myreg.Matches(richtextbox1.text);`" it's working.

```
private void btnGozat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    file = "c:/filelist.txt";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@file, Encoding.Default);
    icerik = sr.ReadToEnd();
    richTextBox1.Text = icerik;//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Regex myreg = new Regex(@"[\d]{1,10}\n{1}(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) --> (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s*([\w ığüşöçĞÜŞİÖÇâêî.!" + "\"" + @":'\-\\?\^,\s]*)(\n)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    mcol = myreg.Matches(richTextBox1.Text);//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<When i change this row it working

    for (int i = 0; i < mcol.Count; i++)
    {
        cbList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

My regex is working I try.

Comment: Use File.ReadAllLines instead.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in Encoding. See what type of encoding your file is using. Encoding.Default is likely ASCII, so you can try with Unicode.